# Retrieve contract information with Web3js

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I am not able to retrieve a contract balance from a smart contract using Web3JS. I do not get an error either.

I have tried calling several other functions in addition to balanceOf and all of the them return the following:

> [Symbol(kWeak)]: WeakReference {}.

Here is the code I am using:

```js
contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call((err, result) => {console.log(result)})
Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [],
     [Symbol(kWeak)]: WeakReference {} } }
```

The expected result should be the balance of the account for the given address.

Comment: I changed the code to "contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call().then(console.log)" and it worked.

Comment: You should post the answer then accept it

Answer (score 0):

I know you find your answer but for how just search for this problem.
you just have to resolve your promise with .then our use async/await syntax to resolve it like below.

```
contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call().then((balance) => console.log(balance))
```

or

```
async function getBalnce(){
    const contract = await new web3Instance.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);
    const balance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(address).call();
    return balance;
}
```